# Kubernetes Helm : How to pass external Ip of dependent service at pod definition?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

**Use Case:** We have created two services S1 & S2 in k8s cluster. The service S2 is dependent on service S1. S1 is created with type LoadBalancer which needs to access outside the kubernetes cluster. The user will only be authenticated at S2. So, the user calls S2 API to get the endpoint of S1 which is nothing but External IP.

Using helm how do we pass the External IP of S1 to the pod of S2 at runtime?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried one solution by calling Kubernetes apiserver to fetch the external ip within the pod but this is not the correct solution as it requires  role creation to get the api access and also need to inject the script for calling api in the init container.

Comment: This doesn't seem very secure. The user could cache the IP and thereafter, access S1, even after their account was deleted, until the IP address changed, which might not happen for a long time.

Comment: It would be preferable to use Ingress instead of LoadBalancer to expose S1. Then the host and path for S1 can be specified in the values file of a combined chart and S2 would be able to access S1 using that external host and path.